# fill a zmm from two ymms in C

Tags: c, intrinsics, avx2, avx512

I am wondering what is the best way to load a m512i from two m256is, with simple packing (zmm0 = {ymm1,ymm0}). I know ymm0 is the lower bits of zmm0, but not sure if I can leverage it in C using intrinsic. What's the best way to achieve this in C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strange, there doesn't seem to be a 256->512 version of `_mm256_set_m128i` in Intel's intrinsics guide.  Perhaps because every AVX512 intrinsic has to have a `_mask_` version?  No, there's still `_mm512_set_epi32`, so that's odd.

You can `_mm512_cast` one to `__m512i` and [`vinserti32x8`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vinserti128:vinserti32x4:vinserti64x2:vinserti32x8:vinserti64x4) the other into it.  (Or 64x4, the choice is irrelevant if not masking.)

```
#include <immintrin.h>

__m256i merge256(__m128i lo, __m128i hi){
        //return _mm256_set_m128i(hi, lo);
        return _mm256_set_m128i(hi, lo);
}

#ifdef __AVX512F__
__m512i merge512(__m256i lo, __m256i hi){
    __m512i base = _mm512_castsi256_si512(lo);  // upper half is don't-care
    return _mm512_inserti32x8(base, hi, 1);     // insert hi as new upper half
    
//        return _mm512_set_m256i(b, a);  // doesn't exist in GCC, clang, ICC, or MSVC
}
#endif
```

[Demo on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/a61fzEe3o), also including 128->256 with `_mm256_set_m128i(hi, lo)`

I defined the arg order as lo, hi for these examples.  You may prefer to define it as hi, lo to match the `_mm_set` (rather than `setr`) intrinsics.